# how to output strings of an array to a text file in java

Tags: java

I am reading text from one file and appending to another file using parallel string arrays, but I keep getting the error Market.java:84: error: no suitable method found for write(String,String,String,String,String,String,String) and I can't find a way to fix it.
My Program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Market {

    private FileWriter output;

    String[] market = new String[100];
    String[] name = new String[100];
    String[] street = new String[100];
    String[] city = new String[100];
    String[] state = new String[100];
    String[] country = new String[100];

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            output = new FileWriter("report.txt", true);
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            System.err.println("You do not have write access to this file.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.err.println("Error opening or creating file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void ReadMarket() {

        try {
            BufferedReader readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("markets.txt"));
            String strRead;

            while ((strRead = readbuffer.readLine()) != null) {

                int i = 0;

                String splitarray[] = strRead.split("\t");
                String firstentry = splitarray[0];
                String secondentry = splitarray[1];
                String thirdentry = splitarray[2];
                String fourthentry = splitarray[3];
                String fithentry = splitarray[4];
                String sixthentry = splitarray[5];

                market[i] = firstentry;
                name[i] = secondentry;
                street[i] = thirdentry;
                city[i] = fourthentry;
                state[i] = fithentry;
                country[i] = sixthentry;

                Writer.write("%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s\n", market[i], name[i], street[i], city[i], state[i], country[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Not Working");
        }
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's because the method:

```
     Writer.write("%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s\n", market[i], name[i], street[i], city[i], state[i], country[i]);
```

Doesn't exist, please link to a javadoc if you know of such a method existing!

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
Writer.write("%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s\n", market[i], name[i], street[i], city[i], state[i], country[i]);
```

to:

```
output.write(String.format("%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s\n", market[i], name[i], street[i], city[i], state[i], country[i]));
```

Reason for the error:

1. write() in [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) class is not static and you are trying to use it as static.
2. write() in [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) class does not have a method to take variable number of arguments.
3. You have created instance of [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) (output) and you should use it to write the data.

Comment: Good solution, thank you for providing it on top of the explanation of the error!

Answer (score 0):

`Writer.write` does not take the amount of parameters you are trying to pass. One of the `write` method takes a `String`. So you may want to format the contents in a string and then pass on to `write` method.

Try this:

```
Writer.write(String.format("%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s\n", market[i], name[i], street[i], city[i], state[i], country[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is no such method in the `FileWriter` class. To write the data in the format you require, you can do something like this

```
String toWriteString = String.format("%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s%-30s%-20s\n", market[i], name[i], street[i], city[i], state[i], country[i]); // Use String format to get the String in the format you required and then write that to the file
output.write(toWriteString); // I believe output is the FileWriter object from what I see in the code
```